# Coding a game, variable with more values?

Tags: python, variables, hyperlink

I'm trying to code a game that resembles "ludo". It's very similar but play ground actually looks like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Menschenaergern.svg/250px-Menschenaergern.svg.png

This is how play ground is being printed:

```
print("      ",pos1,pos2,pos3)
print("      ",pos32, "D",pos4)
print("      ",pos31, "D",pos5)
print("",pos27,pos28,pos29,pos30,"D",pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9)
print("",pos26,"D D D X D D D",pos10)
print("",pos25,pos24,pos23,pos22,"D",pos11,pos12,pos13,pos14)
print("      ",pos21, "D",pos5)
print("      ",pos20, "D",pos5)
print("      ",pos19,pos18,pos17)
```

Before this print function, I have defined all these variables from pos1 to pos32 to be *. It looks like a regular playground.

Everything works fine except that after a player A throws a dice, his position gets bigger according to the number he threw, for example: position = position + throw. What I need to do, is next time it prints the board (playground), it should show the player with his new position. I'm not sure how to link his current position to the variables. Any ideas? Thanks in adv
ance.

Comment: You absolutely need to stop using those numbered variables and use lists/dicts instead. Otherwise you end up with an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Okay I completely agree, I have made a dictionary with all the pos. I still don't know how exactly I can do what I need. I need for function to print a board with stars but still to have a hidden number value so I know where should player A or B move.